# STL copy implementation

Tags: stl, iterator, copy

The following is the definition of copy, according to http://www.sgi.com/tech/stl/copy.html.

```
template<class InputIterator, class OutputIterator>
  OutputIterator copy (InputIterator first, InputIterator last, OutputIterator result)
{
   while (first != last) *result++ = *first++;
   return result;
}
```

I wrote the following code.

```
vector<int> v;
set<int> s;

s.insert(7);
s.insert(11);
s.insert(27);

//copy elements from the set into the vector
copy(s.begin(), s.end(), v.begin());
```

Why does the call to copy above generate a runtime error but not a compile error? I'm assuming it has to do with the fact that the vector is empty, v.begin() == v.end(). But why?

Also, I fixed the code by changing it to the following.

```
copy(s.begin(), s.end(), back_inserter(v));
```

Function back_inserter returns an iterator of type back_insert_iterator>. Why does this work? What is it doing?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It fails because you're not respecting the third precondition listed on this same site:

> There is enough space to hold all of the elements being copied. More
>   formally, the requirement is that [result, result + (last - first)) is
>   a valid range. [1]

An empty vector is smaller than a set of 3 elements, so you cannot perform the copy operation (which really should be called an "overwrite" operation). This information is not known at compile-time and therefore there is no compile-time failure. Keep in mind that while vectors and most other C++ STL collections are expandable at runtime, they cannot be expanded through their regular iterators operations (which mostly serve the purpose of enumerating items and specifying ranges).

The `back_inserter` function returns a special iterator that will insert elements to end of the collection. This iterator is an *output iterator*, and has very little to do with the iterators you can obtain through the `begin()` and `end()` methods of the vector. You cannot read from an output iterator.

Answer (score 0):

Think of the simple case of arrays - with pointers for their iterators. Now, imagine s and v were arrays. If s had 3 elements and v 0 and you tried to copy s into v it wouldn't work. If however v had 3 elements, then the copy would work, over-writing the current contents.

The iterator model in the STL is a generalisation of this. Indeed, pointers can be used as iterators, but so can other objects (you can call `copy` with a pointer to the first element of an array and one to just past the end and it works). It therefore doesn't work for precisely the same reason.

`back_inserter` is an iterator which is intended for just this case; rather than move through the collection overwriting its current position, it increases the size of the collection (which must of course therefore be a collection that can grow, such as vector) and writes to the new position.